# AngularJS - Mocking the DOM Before Module Call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, dom, mocking

So I'm trying to test a large module that has tons of controllers/services etc. I cannot change how the module works fundamentally.

In one of its services it retrieves data from the DOM.

```
appURL: document.getElementById("appURL").value
```

I get null is not an object at that line, which means I have to mock the DOM.

```
describe('..', function() {
    // module must be before inject
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp')); //error

  var $controller;

  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_$controller_, $compile, $rootScope, $document) {
    $controller = _$controller_;
    var scope = $rootScope.$new();
    var element = $compile('<input type="hidden" id="appURL" value="//localhost:3005"></input>')(scope);
    angular.element($document[0].body).append(element);
  }));

  describe......
}
```

So how do I mock the DOM before the module call?

Comment: You may want to take a look at the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing

That being said, checkout jsdom (https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) and consider having your tests run in a browser than in the console.

Comment: Hi, I was following the docs. jsdom doesn't compile at all for me. Unexpected token ')'. Implemented it the same way as their docs.